# Quaternion camera stretching object

Tags: rotation, quaternions

I've been implementing camera movement using quaternions. Im making a game where you have a plane in front of you and you fly around but when you apply yaw the object just stretches almost infinitely and I cannot seem to figure out why. I tried also implementing roll but this also behaves quite odd where it flicks to 90 degree roll instantly.
First time using Quaternions and would appreciate any insight into where I might be going wrong.

[Quaternion_functions.cpp](https://pastebin.com/fAFNApkh)

```
void Update()
{
    auto up = vec3(0, 1, 0);
    auto forward = vec3(1,0,0);
    forward.Rotate(m_yaw, up);
    forward = forward.unit();
 
    vec3 r = up;
    r = r.cross(forward);
    r = r.unit();
    forward.Rotate(m_pitch, r);
        
    vec3 u = forward.cross(r);
    u = u.unit();
 
    m_direction = forward;
    m_up = u;
        
    if(m_roll != 0)
    {
       Quaternion roll(m_roll, forward);
       roll.Normalize();
       Quaternion result = roll * forward * roll.Conjugate();
       result.Normalize();
       Matrix rot = result.ToRotationMatrix();
 
       auto f = rot * vec4(forward.x, forward.y, forward.z, 1.0);
       auto upper = rot * vec4(up.x, up.y, up.z, 1.0);
       auto right = rot * vec4(r.x, r.y, r.z, 1.0);
 
       m_direction = vec3(f.x, f.y, f.z);
       m_direction.unit();
       m_up = vec3(upper.x, upper.y, upper.z);
       m_up.unit();
       r = vec3(right.x, right.y, right.z);
       r.unit();     
    }
 
m_viewMatrix = Matrix::constructView(m_position, (m_position + m_direction), m_up);
 
    }
```